# Как определить безличное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

Поспорил я с одним коллегой по поводу следующего предложения: "Это плохо, если душа спит, если она отвлечена, заглушена побочными обстоятельствами..." Он считает, что главное предложение здесь двусоставное, а я считаю, что безличное. Кто из нас прав?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rus.1september.ru/articlef.php?ID=200501306

Вызывает затруднения определение характера грамматических основ главной части предложений типа 
74) Мне нравится, что я больна не вами. (М.Цветаева) 
В таких случаях надо установить, позицию какого члена предложения занимает придаточная часть. Для этого подставляем от сказуемого к придаточному два двойных вопроса кто? что? и кого? что?(нельзя ограничиваться одним вопросом что?, ведь он не позволяет различить позиции подлежащего и дополнения). В приведенном предложении: нравится кто? что? что я – придаточное занимает позицию подлежащего, следовательно, главное предложение двусоставное, так как имеет позиции двух главных членов, но неполное, так как позиция подлежащего замещена не словоформой, а предикативной единицей (предложением). Важно и следствие: нравится – личный глагол в форме третьего лица.
Другой пример: 
75) Как грустно, что мы не встретились раньше. 
Анализируем грамматическую основу главной части. Сказуемое налицо – грустно. Определяем позицию придаточной путем подстановки двух двойных вопросов: Грустно – кто? что? или кого? что? Здесь – кто? что?, то есть придаточное занимает позицию подлежащего, следовательно, главная часть двусоставная неполная (а значит, грустно – краткое прилагательное). 
Одновременно к придаточному можно подставить другой вопрос: грустно отчего?, значит, оно занимает и позицию обстоятельства. 
Позиция подлежащего в таком случае отсутствует, и главная часть расценивается как односоставная безличная (а значит, грустно – слово категории состояния). Важный вывод: главная часть синкретичная, она одновременно двусоставная и односоставная, синкретична и морфологическая природа сказуемого (грустно – одновременно и краткое прилагательное, и слово категории состояния).

*Следовательно, в предложении "Это плохо, если душа спит, если она отвлечена, заглушена побочными обстоятельствами..." главная часть_Это плохо* - одновременно двусоставная и односоставная.

Answer (score 0):

Подлежащее — (что?) ЭТО, сказуемое — (каково?) ПЛОХО. Это (каково?) плохо.
*Какова, каково, каков* — это вопросы краткого прилагательного, которое всегда является сказуемым. В безличном предложении нет и не может быть подлежащего в именительном падеже.
К глаголу можно подставить местоимения: мне, нам, вам, ему, тебе.
Например: Сегодня не спится. — Сегодня мне (тебе, ему, вам) не спится. Предложение двусоставное. Главное предложение — ЭТО ПЛОХО. 
Остальные — придаточные условия.